# How to connect to a service running on docker container from withing host MacOS machine?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I am trying to install Hadoop on Docker on top of docker-machine. Long story short, I need to be able to `curl 172.17.0.1:8500`.

That works just fine from within the Virtual Machine but fails from within MacOS.

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to 172.17.0.1:8500; Operation timed out
```

What should I do to go around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krisztian Horvath from `sequenceiq/docker-ambari` was kind enough to help me out with that.

So, what you need to do is to

```
docker-machine ip default
```

to get `VM_IP` your virtual machine IP and then

```
sudo route add -net 172.17.0.0/16 VM_IP
```

Comment: what is 172.17.0.0/16 ?

Comment: That's the ip address of your container masked with 16 bits, so that last two numbers don't matter. It's like saying: if anyone asks for 172.17.*.* route it through VM_IP

Comment: Thank you very much. I should have know this was the issue but reading it in response to the question made the lightbulb come on :)